# Expectation of conditional probability generating function

Tags: probability

I have an expression for a conditional probability generating function (pgf) $P_{Y|N}(z)=(1-q+qz)^{Nm}$, where $N\overset{d}{\sim}Bi(n,p)$.
I need to use this to find the pgf for Y, $P_Y(z)$.

I know that $P_Y(z)=E[P_{Y|N}(z)]$, but it is here that I run into a conceptual problem in that how do I find the expectation of a conditional pgf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf G_Y(z)~=~& \mathsf E(z^Y) & \textsf{by definition of pgf} \\[1ex] =~&\mathsf E(\mathsf E(z^Y\mid N)) & \textsf{via Iterated Expectation}\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf E(\mathsf G_{Y\mid N}(z)) & \textsf{by definition of conditional pgf} \\[1ex]=~& \mathsf E((1-q+qz)^{mN}) & \textsf{for the given pgf of }(Y\mid N) \\[1ex]=~& \mathsf G_N((1-q+qz)^m) & \textsf{by definition of pgf} \\[1ex] =~& (1-p+p(1-q+qz)^m)^n &\textsf{for the given pgf of }N\end{align}$$

That is all.